# Add value textbox whe onChange

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want add value textbox into another textboxt when onchange
like this totorial but this tutorial save value to alert

```js
$('#selector').change(function () {
    alert($('#selector').val());
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="selector">
<input type="text" id="value">
```

[tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/ekhT4/1569/)

I want to be like this

[image]

> how can I make it?

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#selector').change(function () {
    alert($('#selector').val());
    $('#selector2').val($('#selector').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="selector">
     <input type="text" id="selector2">
```

Comment: If you follow the fiddle link in the question, OP has included jQuery

Comment: yeah, but how if alert changed to textbox. in order the value into textbox

Comment: @DickyMahardika is this what u want or i delete my answer

Comment: wait, that is what I want, thanks...

Comment: it was just a guess, nice to hear that